# Flash recognized by `lsusb`, but not mounted in /media

Tags: mount

My Ubuntu 16.04 recognizes my flash memory and it works well. But when I use another flash, it's not recognized(this second flash works on other devices). `lsusb` shows the devise, but `ls /media/user` shows nothing.

This is the output of my `lsusb`:

> Bus 002 Device 006: ID 154b:005b PNY Flash Drive

How can I mount it?

Comment: I believe it may be easier to get the answer for this question here: https://superuser.com/ .

Comment: Watch the log messages with `journalctl --follow` while you insert the card.

Comment: Unfortunately, I don't understand the output. It's long but this part is printed in red:  `print_req_error: I/O error, dev sr0, sector 1060`

Comment: Does your Ubuntu system see the drive as a mass storage device? Please edit your original question to add the output of the following commands, `sudo lsblk -f` ; `sudo lsblk -m` ; `sudo parted -ls` ; `df -h`